# How to discover the layout of an svn repo for an svn2git conversion?

Tags: git, svn, github, git-svn

I'm attempting to convert an `svn` repo over to `git`, however I'm not entirely sure of the layout the current `svn` repo is using.  As I'm not adept with `svn` I am not sure how to peak inside of `svn` and ascertain exactly what I should be using for the proper conversion string for [`svn2git` usage](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git#usage)

If I can determine this I would then be able to easily pick the option from those listed there.  Would appreciate any help knowing how to find this out in svn!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`svn list http://repository`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html) to see the contents of a SVN repository.